# How to access to windows clipboard from office 365 Excel web addin?

Tags: excel, typescript, office365, office-js, excel-addins

I am trying to create my own custom excel web add-in using Visual Studio mainly to be used for desktop. I was able to manipulate with active sheet, ranges etc. On add-in side, I want to perform some specific actions depending on the clipboard content. 
Is it actually possible to access the windows clipboard content from add-in which as I understand uses TypeScript?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to copy excel formula using an office add-in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31960093/is-it-possible-to-copy-excel-formula-using-an-office-add-in)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is currently not a way to access the clipboard from the office application.

If you can, take a moment to jump over to [UserVoice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com) and recommend it so others can vote it up. Our teams look at these suggestions often.

This has been asked before, so we will take this into account when reviewing. 
Previous Ask: [Is it possible to copy excel formula using an office add-in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31960093/is-it-possible-to-copy-excel-formula-using-an-office-add-in)

Comment: It's better to flag the question as a duplicate instead of answering it for a second time with the same information.

Comment: Thank you Nico. There is a bit different context in this question, and a different API if implemented in Excel. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

There is no official API, but the add-in DOM implements the deprecated [Document.execCommand() API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand) which includes `"copy"`, `"cut"` and `"paste"`. With hidden input fields and selection manipulation, clipboard access is theoretically possible (I've implemented writing to the clipboard).

Comment: How did you do that? Maybe I have the same issue. I have a ui-less Office add-in to copy the current URL of the opened document, but I don't have any luck. I tried all kinds of "copy" actions, but everything is not working. Please answer to [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65149982/how-to-copy-url-to-windows-clipboard-in-office-add-in)